# apply multiple functions to $_POST array in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops, http-post

i was wondering, instead of tedious and repetitive code to sanitize input data is there a simpler way to manipulate the $_POST array and apply e.g. strip_tags() and remove_trailing_spaces() to all elements, in a successive loop?

Comment: Do you mean something like `foreach($_POST as $postField){ something; }`?
If yes, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: how about putting them in a function?

Comment: It's an array like any other, so of course … but you shouldn't because how you sanitise data depends on where you are going to put it, not where you are getting it from.

Comment: please ask correct questions

Comment: data goes to mysql, a sanitize all data the same, regardless of input, given that i am still learning input specific sanitazion plays no role for me. i' look further into the first three answers, latter one is of no use, thanks

Comment: no malicious intentions in regard to the topmost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it like this

```
function getSanitizedData($index){
    return sanitize($_POST[$index]);
}

function sanitize($value){
    return remove_trailing_spaces(striptags(stripslashes($value)));
}
```

Now instead of using $_POST, always use getSanitizedData function

OR

Just use `PHP Magic Quotes`

http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php

Comment: upon calling getSantizedData() do you use a loop to go through the indices?

Comment: Do you see me using any kind of loop? Its just a O(1) operation.

Comment: Magic Quotes has been removed from PHP.